# not(A XOR B) =?

Tags: xor, algebra

the question relates to the following simplification:
[image]

How does A( not(BC) +BC ) = A*not(B XOR C) ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

"(not(B) and not(C)) or (B and C)" is only true for "B equals C".

That is equivalent to "not(B unequal C)" which is "not(B exor C)".

In proper formatting:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If we see the truth table we can get the answer[image: truth table]

Now we can see that BC or(not(B) and not(C)) is equal to not(B xor C)